# Custom pager control

Tags: asp.net, paging, repeater

I develop a custom data pager control. Its "previous" and "next" hyperLink buttons don't work properly and I don't understand why.

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server">
<HeaderTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbFirst" CommandName="<%#PageChangedItemCommand %>" CommandArgument="1" runat="server">&laquo;</asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;
     <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbPrevious" CommandName="<%#PageChangedItemCommand %>" CommandArgument="<%#PreviousPageIndex%>"  runat="server">&lt;</asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;
 </HeaderTemplate>   
<ItemTemplate> 
    <asp:LinkButton  CommandName="<%#PageChangedItemCommand %>" CommandArgument="<%#Container.DataItem.ToString()%>"  ID="p" runat="server" ><%#Container.DataItem.ToString()%>&nbsp;</asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>

<FooterTemplate>
     <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbNext" CommandName="<%#PageChangedItemCommand %>" CommandArgument="<%#NextPageIndex%>"  runat="server">&gt;</asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;
     <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbLast" CommandName="<%#PageChangedItemCommand %>" CommandArgument="<%#PagesCount%>" runat="server">&raquo;</asp:LinkButton>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>



public partial class Pager : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
        public int PageSize { get; set; }
        public int DataItemsCount { get; set; }


        private int _pagesCount;
        public int PagesCount
        {

            get
            {
                if (DataItemsCount % PageSize == 0)
                    return _pagesCount = (DataItemsCount / PageSize);

                else
                    return _pagesCount = ((DataItemsCount / PageSize) + 1);
            }

            private set
            {
                _pagesCount = value;
            }
        }

        public event EventHandler<PageChangedEventArgs> PageChanged;
        protected const string PageChangedItemCommand = "PageChanged";
        private const string CurrentPageCssStyle = "font-weight:bold; font-size:15px;";

        private void RaiseEvent(int currentPage)
        {
            if (PageChanged != null)
                PageChanged(this, new PageChangedEventArgs(currentPage));
        }

        protected List<int> DataSource
        {
            get
            {
                List<int> pages = new List<int>();
                for (int i = 1; i <= PagesCount; i++)
                    pages.Add(i);

                return pages;
            }
        }

        protected int NextPageIndex { get { return CurrentPage + 1; } }
        protected int PreviousPageIndex { get { return CurrentPage -1; } }

        public Pager()
        {
            CurrentPage = 1;
            PageSize = 1;
            DataItemsCount = 1;
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rpt.ItemCommand += new RepeaterCommandEventHandler(rpt_ItemCommand);
            rpt.DataSource = DataSource;
            rpt.DataBind();

          //  
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                CurrentPageSetCssStyle(CurrentPageCssStyle);
                // SetupCommandArguments();
            }
        }

        void rpt_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == PageChangedItemCommand)
            {
                CurrentPage = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
                CurrentPageSetCssStyle(CurrentPageCssStyle);
               // SetupCommandArguments();
                RaiseEvent(CurrentPage);

            }
        }



        private void CurrentPageSetCssStyle(string style)
        {
            foreach (RepeaterItem item in rpt.Items)
            {
                LinkButton lnkButton = item.FindControl("p") as LinkButton;
                if (lnkButton != null)
                {
                    if (lnkButton.CommandArgument == CurrentPage.ToString())
                        lnkButton.Attributes.Add("style", style);
                }
            }
          //  SetupCommandArguments();
        }



        void SetupCommandArguments()
        {
            LinkButton lnkbPrevious = rpt.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("lnkbPrevious") as LinkButton;
            if (lnkbPrevious != null)
                lnkbPrevious.CommandArgument = (CurrentPage - 1).ToString();

            LinkButton lnkbNext = rpt.Controls[rpt.Controls.Count - 1].Controls[0].FindControl("lnkbNext") as LinkButton;
            if (lnkbPrevious != null)
                lnkbPrevious.CommandArgument = (CurrentPage + 1).ToString();
        }

    }
```

I need to develop my own paging light control. Don't suggest me to use other paging controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had to do a custom pager in the last few days, but I went about it slightly differently.

I chose to use two repeaters: 
1. This one was for the paging

```
<div class="searchResultsPaging" runat="server">
        <asp:Repeater ID="Paging" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <a href='<%# Eval("PageUrl") %>' class='<%# (Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsCurrent")) == true)? "pagingButtonOff" : "pagingButtonOn" %>'>
                    <%# Eval("PageText") %></a>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
```

2. Was for the items I'm display

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Properties" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="propertyCard">
                <div class="propertyTitle">
                    <a href='/property/<%# Eval("Id") %>'>
                        <%# Eval("Title") %></a></div>
                <div class="propertySuburb">
                    <%# Eval("Suburb") %></div>
                <img src='/_Remove/SamplePropertyImages/<%# Eval("PriorityImage") %>' width="190"
                    height="143" alt='Property for sale in <%# Eval("Suburb")%>' />
                <div class="propertyFeatures">
                    <img src="/_Remove/Icons/Bed.gif" alt='<%# Eval("Suburb") %>, <%# Eval("City") %> property has <%# Eval("Bedrooms") %> bedrooms.' /><%# Eval("Bedrooms") %><img
                        src="/_Remove/Icons/Bath.gif" alt='<%# Eval("Suburb") %>, <%# Eval("City") %> property has <%# Eval("Bathrooms") %> bedrooms.' /><%# Eval("Bathrooms") %></div>
                <div class="propertyPrice">
                    <%# Eval("Price","{0:###,##0.00}") %>
                </div>
                <a href="#">View Property Details</a>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

During binding, my business logic returned a list of properties and a total count. From there it was easy to bind and build the paging controls.

Might not work for you since you're looking for page next/back type functionality.

Regards,
Jacqueds

Comment: The complete C# code wouldn't do you much good. We've rigged the solution to work with extensionless URLs and we omitted postbacks altogether by making each page number button browse to the next page instead.